# How do I validate a Captcha FIRST in a Zend Framework 2 Form?

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I'd like to skip validating other elements in the form if the Captcha fails.  I understand there's a break_chain_on_failure variable tucked away in there, but can't find docs on how to set it for the Captcha

e.g., given this form, how to make Captcha validate first?

```
class Registration extends Form implements InputFilter\InputFilterProviderInterface
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct('registration');

        /*
         * Phone
         */
        $phone = new Element\Text('phone');
        $phone->setLabel( "Phone")
            ->setAttribute( 'class', 'form-control bfh-phone' )
            ->setAttribute( 'data-format', '(ddd) ddd-dddd' );
        $this->add( $phone );


        /*
         * CAPTCHA
         */
        $theme          = 'clean';
        $locale         = isset( $_COOKIE['locale'] ) ? $_COOKIE['locale'] : 'en_US';
        list( $lang,  ) = explode( "_", $locale, 2 );

        $recaptcha = new Captcha\ReCaptcha();
        $recaptcha
            ->setOption( 'theme', $theme )
            ->setPubKey( '6Ld-&amp;hl='.$lang)
            ->setPrivKey( '6Ld-' )
            ->setMessage( _( "Correctly repeat the text in the image, in the box beneath it" ) );



        $captcha = new Element\Captcha( 'captcha' );
        $captcha->setCaptcha( $recaptcha )
            ->setLabel( 'Please verify that you are human' );
        $this->add( $captcha );

    }

}
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: The Forms InputFilter is run in the order the Filters/Validators are inserted. Simply add the captcha inputfilter first ;)

Comment: Hi @Sam.  I actually do have it set up that way (first), but the whole darned thing validates nonetheless (all error messages shown).  I'll keep digging I suppose..

Answer (score 0):

It turns out, that you can't do it through conventional means; the Captcha element assigns itself its own validator, so the typical validator block doesn't stand.  You can see this in the default Filter factory, if it is an instance of ValidatorInterface, it skips the whole breakOnFailure assignment.  Solution to work around this was to add the ValidatorManager and FilterManager to my form through DI:

**This is my form object's constructor**

```
public function __construct( AuthenticationFormInterface $authentication, Array $config, $filter_manager, $validator_manager )
{
    parent::__construct('registration');

    $chain  = new FilterChain();
    $chain->setPluginManager($filter_manager);
    $this->getFormFactory()
        ->getInputFilterFactory()
            ->setDefaultFilterChain( $chain );

    $chain  = new ValidatorChain();
    $chain->setPluginManager( $validator_manager );
    $this->getFormFactory()
        ->getInputFilterFactory()
            ->setDefaultValidatorChain( $chain );
```

Its **factory** looks like so

```
'FooForm' => function( $sm ){
                $config = $sm->get('config');
                $form   = new \LDP\Form\Registration( $sm->get('LDP\Service\Authentication'), $config['launchfire-app']['registration'], $sm->get('FilterManager'), $sm->get('ValidatorManager') );
                return $form;
            },
```

And in the controller where I use it, I added this line just before isValid()

```
$form->getInputFilter()->get('captcha')->setBreakOnFailure( true );
```

Now, it validates first and breaks on failure.